# Is it possible to use MemoizedSelector as an input parameter for createSelector?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, memoization, ngrx-store

I'm trying to create a MemoizedSelector with `createSelector`. I want to use another MemoizedSelector as it's input. But after root state is changed this selector doesn't recalculate new selected value.

E.g. we have a state:

```
const initialState: RootState = {
  user: {
    name: {
      first: 'John',
      last: 'Doe',
    },
  },
};
```

and a chain of reducers:

```
const userSelector = (state: RootState) => state.user;

const nameSelector : MemoizedSelector<RootState, UserName> = createSelector(
  userSelector,
  (user: User) => user.name
);

const lastNameSelector : MemoizedSelector<RootState, string>  = createSelector(
  nameSelector,
  (userName: UserName) => userName.last
);
```

So when we select the first name and change it in a reducer:

```
this.store$.select(lastNameSelector).subscribe(it => console.log(it));
this.store$.dispatch({type:'CHANGE_LAST_NAME', payload: 'Brown'});
```

We can't see "Brown" in the log.

I can make it work with clean function:

```
const lastNameSelector = (state: RootState) => state.user.name.last;
```

but I want to take advantage of memoization, and don't recalculate user's last name when any other state param is changed.
What can I do to make it work?

Example app: https://github.com/vadim-shb/ngrx-issue

**UPDATE:**

The issue was in the reducer:

```
export function userReducer(state: UserData = initialState, action: any) {
  if (action.type === 'CHANGE_LAST_NAME') {
    let result = {
      ...state
    };
    result.name.last = action.payload;
    return result;
  }
  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your reducer, try this:

```
if (action.type === 'CHANGE_LAST_NAME') {
    let result = {
      ...state,
      name: {
        ...state.name,
        last: action.payload
      }
     }
    return result;
  }
```